# react-mapbox-gl accessing lat and lon on click

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using the [react-mapbox-gl library](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl) and I am trying to access the lon/lat from the [Mapbox Api](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#mapmouseevent) on triggering an event on the map. I don't really understand where/how to access that info. I know that React has `ref` for accessing child states but am not sure how that fits in with this library.

[The Mapbox Api](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#mapmouseevent)

an example

```
    <Map
      style={mapStyle}
      center={mapCenter}
      containerStyle={mapContainerStyle}

      //onDblClick access the lon lat somehow. 

    >
    </Map>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of [react-mapbox-gl@2.1.0](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md#events).

```
<Map onDblClick={handleClick} />
```

which points to

```
function handleClick(map, event) {
  var lngLat = event.lngLat;
}
```